# How to get token of currently rendered document in screen?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-presentation-language

My `pause` handler handles pause action from multiple cards. Here is my `PauseHandler` looks like,

```
    @Override
    public Optional<Response> handle(HandlerInput input) {
                
        List<Command> commands = new LinkedList<Command>();       
        ControlMediaCommand pauseVideoCommand = ControlMediaCommand.builder()
                .withCommand(MediaCommandType.PAUSE)
                .withComponentId(PLAYER_COMPONENT_ID).build();
        commands.add(pauseVideoCommand);

        ExecuteCommandsDirective executeCommandDirective = 
                ExecuteCommandsDirective.builder()
                .withToken(Constants.DOCUMENT_TOKEN)
                .withCommands(commands)
                .build();
        
        String speechText = "Okay";
        return input.getResponseBuilder()
                .withSpeech(speechText)
                .addDirective(executeCommandDirective)
                .build();
       }
}
```

Now my pause handler needs to handle `pause` via voice for another APL document. I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to uniquely identify the document (something like token) while handling pause so that i can choose appropriate action for pause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use session attributes to store a token for the last document sent when you send it.

https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs/manage-attributes.html

Comment: That's a good suggestion. But I'm worried about the following case, where I've three cards (C1, C2, C3). Out of which two(C1, C2) of them are supporting video and one of them(C3) is supporting only text. What would happen if I've played video in C1 and then C3 comes to foreground and execute pause/resume command? Where would I clear the session attribute?

Comment: I haven't done this, but in theory... set a listener for the event that swaps C3 for C1 and use a sendEvent in APL to trigger a handler in your back-end code that can clear or change that session variable. https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/alexa-presentation-language/apl-standard-commands.html#sendevent-command